# Installing a development app with Apple Configurator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile, apple-configurator

I need to install a prototype app on 50 iPads, for a real time test with 50 users. It is not on the AppStore. The app is developed using most recent XCode, Swift, and a valid ad-hoc provisioning profile and development certificate. I can not create an enterprise account (too expensive), and would like to use an ad-hoc provisioning profile.

I have been able to create an "archive" (.ipa file), with following setup : built using "Generic iOS device", compatible with all kinds of devices. This is an universal app.

People who prepare the iPads using Apple Configurator can install the app, but the icon disappears immediately. I have sent them my provisioning profiles, but they say it is not working. Maybe I did not send the correct one ? Shall I declare all the devices UDID on my Apple Dev Account - that is my idea, but a bit difficult - ?

Anybody has an idea ? Maybe this is simply not possible. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use TestFlight. In this case you shouldn't declare devices UDID.

Another way - install via .ipa. In this case you must declare all the devices UDID in your Apple Dev Account. Rebuild! your app only after added all devices. After this, upload your .ipa to https://www.diawi.com and share received link (for ex. by Skype), that users should to open on their devices and install app.

Comment: I'll try both. TestFlight seems more suitable for what I need. Thank you for these precisions, and for the diawi solution.